# Is there a name for, and some significance of, $\mathbb E e^{X^T \Omega X}$?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-function, quadratic-form

Let $X \in \mathbb R^r$ be a random vector. The moment generating function (MGF) $m(t) = \mathbb E e^{X^Tt}$ is ubiquitous in statistics and probability.

In my research, I've had to deal with the scalar-valued matrix function $M(\Omega) = \mathbb E e^{X^T\Omega X}$. **I'm interested in knowing whether this function has a name, and if it has some significance more generally?**

The only thing I could come up with myself was that, since $\mathrm{vec(X^T\Omega X)} = (X^T \otimes X^T)\mathrm{vec}(\Omega)$, it can be thought of as the MGF for $X \otimes X$.

Comment: There's scarcely a question to be answered here: by inserting a suitable variable (say "$-t$" or "$it$") in the expression, exactly as in the first example, you obtain the mgf for the quadratic form $X^\prime \Omega X$, $$M_{X^\prime\Omega X}(t) = \mathbb{E}e^{-tX^\prime\Omega X}.$$

Comment: I think there is a legitimate question here.  The matrix $\Omega$ in the equation of interest to you is acting as the multiplicative element in a quadratic form, as opposed to the $t$ which acts as the multiplicative element in the linear function in the exponential of an MGF.  In any case, I've also run across these before, so they may have some general significance, but I am unaware of any special name for them.  I would suggest just looking them up by description - e.g., exponentials of a quadratic form.